# ERROR {InvokeMediator} - {api:EmailMicroService} Sequence named Value {name ='null', keyValue ='techlogixSmtp'} cannot be found

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

**Scenario**
I'm using Wso2 Email Connector for sending emails to our company's smtp server. Following is the code for connection and Api

**Connection**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="techlogixSmtp" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <email.init>
        <connectionType>SMTPS</connectionType>
        <password>xxxx</password>
        <host>smtp.techlogix.com</host>
        <requireTLS>true</requireTLS>
        <port>25</port>
        <name>techlogixSmtp</name>
        <username>xxxx</username>
    </email.init>
</localEntry>
```

**Api**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/email" name="EmailMicroService" port="8290" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/send">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <email.send configKey="techlogixSmtp">
                <from>{json-eval($.from)}</from>
                <to>{json-eval($.to)}</to>
                <subject>{json-eval($.subject)}</subject>
                <content>{json-eval($.content)}</content>
                <contentType>{json-eval($.contentType)}</contentType>
                <attachments>{json-eval($.attachments)}</attachments>
            </email.send>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Question**
I'm facing the ERROR {InvokeMediator} - {api:EmailMicroService} Sequence named Value {name ='null', keyValue ='techlogixSmtp'} cannot be found. What possible configuration is missing from my end which is causing this issue?

**I made sure that updated Api is deployed on MicroIntegrator**

Comment: It seems like the local entry `techlogixSmtp` is not deployed properly. Are you packing these in a CAR file? If so make sure the local entry is packed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sanoj, mentioned your Local Entry `techlogixSmtp` seems not deployed to the Runtime. So in your `CompositeExporter` Project make sure your `techlogixSmtp` is checked and the correct `Server Role` is selected. Please refer to the following image.

[image]